# Rack options, how to access options passed to rack like so: $ rackup --option arg1=true

Tags: ruby, rack, cascade

I have searched high and low for any Rack documentation detailing how to access the options the docs say you can pass into a rack app like so:

`$ rackup --server thin --env development --option arg1=true`

In my config.ru I am using Rack::Cascade like so:

`Rack::Cascade.new [myapp1, myapp2]`

I need to access the option passed to Rack via rackup on the command line and make that available to the Ruby apps running in Rack::Cascade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not found a way to do this via rack server instance options. At least not from within a module that is being run via rack cascade.

The way I ended up achieving the same thing was to set an env variable like so:

```
env deployment=true rackup --server thin --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4567 --quiet
```

This way the deployment option can of course be accessed from any of the modules running in rack cascade, like so:

```
ENV['deployment']
```

Answer (score 0):

Rack options can be accessed via `[your_rack_server_instance].options`.

For example, if you initialize rack server like below:

```
rack = Rack::Server.new # or Rack::Server.new(options)
rack.options
#=> {:environment=>"development", :Port=>9292, :Host=>"localhost", :config=>"/Users/abc/workspace/xyz/config.ru"}
```

For details, you can take a look at its implementation:

[Rack::Server](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/server.rb#L184-L215)

[Rack::Builder](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/builder.rb)

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't seem to work in my setup. I'm running rack using Rack::Cascade and I need to access rack options from within the sinatra module that I'm running through Cascade

Comment: sorry, in that case, I'm not sure :(